# Maximum Number of Categorical Outcomes for Multinomial Logistic Regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, many-categories, multinomial-logit

Based on 4 or 5 predictor variables, I would like to determine "affinity" to a group of 26 different non-profits that an individual could potentially donate money to.  I have approximately 1 million records but I have not heard of a multinomial logistic regression used for this many categories and I wasn't sure if I should be advised against this approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific mathematical limit.  There could be limits due to limitations of your software or your computer, such as little memory. Apart from that 26 categories should be no problem with good software.

The paper http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/archive/Research/MMS/PAPERS/authorid-csna05.pdf  about author attribution, using a bayesian version of multinomial logit, uses an example with 114 different authors, plus a category "none of them". Again, 26 should be no problem at all.

With a high number of categories it could show important to use a software implementation that uses sparse matrices.

Comment: To wit: I've been working on a project at work where we have about 1400 categories and a training set of about 40k records. Model-fitting is much slower than you're used to, but it works just fine.